# Compiler Error CS1525 "end of file"

Tags: c#

```
using System;
public class Test
{   
  public static void Main()     
  {    
     string reply; 
     Console.WriteLine("Hi");
     Console.ReadLine.ToUpper();
     if(reply=="BYE")     
         {Console.WriteLine("bye");}    
  }
```

I was trying to mimic the code I found on youtube for a text adventure, but then I get this error called Compiler error saying "prog.cs(14,1): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'" Anyone know the reason why it's saying this?

Comment: you don't have a closing bracket on your class.  On a side note you'll never write out `bye` with this code

Comment: You lost symbol '}' match the Test class

Comment: Well formatted code is important in identifying silly mistakes such as a missing brackets

Comment: After formatting code into multiple lines and aligning curly braces it looks like you are missing closing close brace. So voting to close as "typographical error".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding another curly brace at the bottom (you didn't fully close out the `public class Test`

```
using System;
public class Test
{   
  public static void Main()     
  {    
     string reply; 
     Console.WriteLine("Hi");
     Console.ReadLine.ToUpper();
     if(reply=="BYE")     
         {Console.WriteLine("bye");}    
  }
} //Added Curly Brace
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I knew needed one, but I had no idea to place it.