# Unable to build nunit with xamarin : error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'

Tags: xamarin.ios, nunit

Unable to build basic nUnit project in Xamarin on MAC. 
Below code:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;

namespace DocConnectionAutomation
{
    [TestFixture ()]
    public class Test
    {
        [Test]
        public static void TestTrue()
                {
                        Assert.True(true);
                }
    }
```

which resulted in the below error

```
xbuild DocConnectionAutomation.sln /p:Configuration=Release


Test.cs(13,247): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `end-of-file'

 0 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: What kind of project did you create?

Comment: You seem to be missing a curly brace `}` at the end of your file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler Error CS1525 "end of file"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27370295/compiler-error-cs1525-end-of-file)